# POST a JSON with Basic HTTP Authentication

Tags: java, json, web-services

as the title says, I need to post a json request with basic http authentication. Unfortunately, I do not have any idea as how it is going to happen. Are there any tutorial available online that you guys know or at least a sample code so that I can fully understand what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily through the URL:

`http://username:password@www.posttome.com/create`

Or through the Header:

`Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l`

`QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l == base64_encode_somehow("username" + ":" + "password")`

Comment: @ScaryWombat, true, but it is one of the forms how it works, I also added the `Authorization Header` example to cover both ways..